# Print logs timestamp upto micro/nano second in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I want to print logs with a timestamp with precision up to micro or nanosecond in springboot.

I tried this for `logging.pattern.console` value

1. `'%d{DEFAULT_NANOS} - %msg%n'`
2. `'%d{yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS,nnnnnn} - %msg%n'`
3. `'%d{yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss,nnnnnnnnn} - %msg%n'`

But, I am getting only upto milliseconds. Can someone pls help me in that.

Comment: CPU frequencies are up to Giga Hertz which means even if you get any output in your log it is not accurate at all.

Comment: but still, it will provide me with some clarity that I need.

Comment: what JDK you are using?

Comment: openjdk version "14.0.2"